# Swift 4 How to transfer functions in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have in in my app an function. Is there a way to transfer it to other Viewcontroller? if I use `UserDefaults.standard.set(function(), forKey: "function")`

I don't know how to load it, because

```
let function() = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "function") as? CGFunction
```

doesn't work.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: What did you mean?

Comment: This is wrong. Your function is almost never a variable. There is no need to do this. Either write that function in a global space, or exten a protocol which they both adopt or write it in the baseclass of both these classes. Ot worst case scrnario, copy/paste the function.

Comment: Apart from that `CGFunction` is not property list compliant `UserDefaults` is the wrong place for sharing data between view controllers.

Comment: Hey buddy, I didn't get what are you trying to achieve with that but if you're trying to pass data between viewcontrollers, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31934786/6361488

Answer (score 1):

**Passing and returning functions**

The following function is returning another function as its result which can be later assigned to a variable and called.

```
func jediTrainer () -> ((String, Int) -> String) {
  func train(name: String, times: Int) -> (String) {
    return "\(name) has been trained in the Force \(times) times"
  }
  return train
}

let train = jediTrainer()
train("Obi Wan", 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Swift allows you to pass functions or closures to other objects, since functions and closures are themselves first class objects.

However, you cannot save a function or closure to `UserDefaults`. To the best of my knowledge there is no way to serialize functions or closures, and in any case they certainly are not one of the very small list of types that can be saved to `UserDefaults`. (Known as "property list objects" since the same small set of types can be store to both property lists and to `UserDefaults`.)

Why do you want to pass a function to another view controller?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, functions are Closures. You can simply pass closures in code.

```
Class A {
    var someFunction: (Int) -> String

    init(f: (Int) -> String) {
        someFunction = f
    }
}

func f2(a: Int) -> String {
    return "Value is: \(a)"
}
let AInstance = A(f: f2)
print(AInstance.someFunction(5)) // prints "Value is: 5"
```

or specific `someFunction` as optional like `var someFunction: ((Int) -> String)!` and set it later in code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer your initial question:

> I have in in my app an function. Is there a way to transfer it to other Viewcontroller?

Yes, there is a way: **use your segue** rather than trying to store the function in `userDefaults`.

1) **Make sure that the destination view controller has an instance variable that can hold your function.** (Note that in Swift 4, you'll have to make sure you either set a default value for that variable, or create a custom initializer to ensure the variable is given a value on initialization.)

2) **In the first view controller, wherever you handle your segue, instantiate your destination view controller. Then set the variable to your function.** (You can do this, for example, in an override of the `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method.)